# mysqli_fetch_assoc() is giving a warning that it wants mysqli_result, but object given

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to fetch some data from the database using prepare statements and facing this issue.

this is my code

```
function find_subject_by_id($id){
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id=?";
    //echo $sql;

    /*Create a Prepared statement */
    $result = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);

    /*bind PARAMETERS for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'i', $id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);

    /*bind result variables*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $id, $menu_name, $position, $visible);

    /*fetch value*/
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);

    $subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //the warning is here

    /*close connection*/
    mysqli_stmt_close($result);
    return $subject; //returns an assoc array
  }
```

I am fairly new to prepare statements and just learning, could someone please help me spot what am I missing here.
Please don't mind if the question seems repeated or silly. Thanks !

Comment: I have never worked with statements before, but [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) for mysqli_stmt_fetch states that it already does what you try to do with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: There's only 1 result returned and `mysqli_stmt_fetch` fetches it and at that point there's nothing more to fetch. This is my guess.

Comment: Okay .. got it ! I removed the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and assigned $subject to `mysqli_stmt_fetch` .. the warning is not present now.. thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `mysql_stmt_bind_result` you bind the specific columns to your variables that you specified.
You can then fetch results like this

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
    printf ("%s\n", $menu_name);
}
```

Or using any other variable that you bound to.

**Edit:**

You can use the statement as an associative array doing this:

```
$mysqliresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($result);
```

which will convert it to a `MySqliResult`
After that you can do

```
$subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqliresult);
```

to get the associative array

Comment: But I want to store the fetched data in a associative array and then  display it on the page, notice the `return $subject` 
Also as per your above comment I assigned `$subject` to `mysql_stmt_fetch` , the warning went but the data is not being fetched because the return type of `mysql_stmt_fetch` is boolean